# Facing issue for the below command in sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I have copied the jar file in sqoop/lib folder and the commands which i was using in sqoop is :

> bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop --username root --password admin --table cities

Error Message :

14/06/21 08:44:44 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:772)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:660)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:683)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:223)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:347)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1277)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1089)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:396)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the mysql-connector jar file to sqoop/lib folder to access the mysql database.
and then execute your sqoop command.

download link : `http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6`

Answer (score 0):

Download mysql-connector jar from this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.tar.gz).
Extract and copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar file to $SQOOP_HOME/lib/ directory.
Copy the same jar to lib wich is present in hdfs , if sqoop is using with hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this option

```
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

also make sure you have run the below commands

```
% mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sqoop.* TO ''@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> quit;
Bye
```